# Does sendmail support the BinaryMime ESMTP extension? If so, how can this be enabled?

Tags: email-server, sendmail

Does sendmail support the `BINARYMIME` ESMTP extension? If so, how can this be enabled?

I didn't see this referenced in the bat book or documentation.

Comment: People still use sendmail? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closing the loop on this one in case anyone else is looking for it.  As of July 22, the `BINARYMIME` ESMTP extension is not available in sendmail.  This was confirmed by searching source manually.  The documentation doesn't reference it either.